# Laravel does not appear when browsing VPS's IP

Tags: php, nginx, laravel

I've just installed Laravel 4 with nginx on my ubuntu vps following this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-laravel-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-lts-vps

Evertything seemed to be installed fine, however when browsing it's ip adress, I still get:

> **It works!**
>
> *This is the default web page for this server. The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.*

I thought this could have something to do with the virtual host, but that one seems to be configured correctlt aswell

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server;

    root /var/www/laravel/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Would anynone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your web server should point to the `/public` folder not the root of your laravel application.

That is `/var/www/laravel/public` not `/var/www/laravel/`.

Also make sure you restart your server to load up configuration files.

Comment: I've already edited that mistake on my server, I'm sorry, I'll edit the post

Comment: Did you restart your server ? What is the error on screen ?

Comment: I did, and there's no error displayed, it simply shows the index.html file in the www/ directory